# need help to write a prolog statement

Tags: prolog

I want to write a prolog code to resolve the following game : 
[Crack the 3 digit code based on these statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKKVU.jpg)

Here is my code for the first statement: "One number is correct and well placed", but I get the answer false instead of [six,*,*], [*,eight,*], [*,*,two] :

```
first(X, [X|_]).
second(X, [_,X,_]).
third(X, [_,_,X]).

one_correct_well([A,B,C], [X,Y,Z]):-first(A, [X,Y,Z]), B\=Y, C\=Z.
one_correct_well([A,B,C], [X,Y,Z]):-second(B, [X,Y,Z]), A\=X, C\=Z.
one_correct_well([A,B,C], [X,Y,Z]):-third(C, [X,Y,Z]), B\=Y, A\=X.

solution(CODE):-
CODE = [_,_,_],
one_correct_well([six,eight,two], CODE).
```

Comment: This is basically a simpler version of the [Zebra puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle), I suggest looking into solutions for that one for hints to figure this one out.

Comment: thanks, I understand the solution of the zebra problem but I don't know how to apply it to this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gives me `[zero,four,two]` as the result:

**One digit correct and well placed:**
For [A,B,C], the authorized patterns are :

```
[A,_,_]  
[_,B,_] 
[_,_,C]
```

therefore the following code:

```
one_correct_well([A,B,C],[A,X,Y]):-
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],B,ListB),
    member(X,ListB), % X can take any value different from B
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],C,ListC),
    member(Y,ListC). % Y can take any value different from C
one_correct_well([A,B,C],[X,B,Y]):-
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],A,ListA),
    member(X,ListA),
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],C,ListC),
    member(Y,ListC).
one_correct_well([A,B,C],[X,Y,C]):-
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],A,ListA),
    member(X,ListA),
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],B,ListB),
    member(Y,ListB).
```

**One digit correct but wrongly placed:**
For [A,B,C], the authorized patterns are :

```
[_,A,_]
[_,_,A]  
[B,_,_] 
[_,_,B] 
[C,_,_]
[_,C,_]
```

therefore the following code:

```
one_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[X,A,Y]):-
    not_in2([X,Y],[A,B,C]).
one_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[X,Y,A]):-
    not_in2([X,Y],[A,B,C]).
one_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[B,X,Y]):-
    not_in2([X,Y],[A,B,C]).
one_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[X,Y,B]):-
    not_in2([X,Y],[A,B,C]).
one_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[C,X,Y]):-
    not_in2([X,Y],[A,B,C]).
one_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[X,C,Y]):-
    not_in2([X,Y],[A,B,C]).

not_in2([X,Y],[A,B,C]):- % X and Y are different from A, B and C
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],A,List1),
    delete(List1,B,List2),
    delete(List2,C,List3),
    member(X,List3),
    member(Y,List3).
```

---

**Edit:**
Maybe a more elegant way of writing this :

```
one_correct_wrong([A,B,C],L):-
   (L=[X,A,Y]; % this, OR ..
    L=[X,Y,A]; % .. this, OR ..
    L=[B,X,Y]; % .. this, OR ..
    L=[X,Y,B]; % .. this, OR ..
    L=[C,X,Y]; % .. this, OR ..
    L=[X,C,Y]),
    not_in2([X,Y],[A,B,C]).
```

---

**Two digits correct but wrongly placed:**

```
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[B,A,X]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[B,X,A]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[X,A,B]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[X,C,B]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[C,X,B]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[B,C,X]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[C,X,A]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[C,A,X]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).
two_correct_wrong([A,B,C],[X,C,A]):-
    not_in(X,[A,B,C]).

not_in(X,[A,B,C]):- % X is different from A, B and C
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],A,List1),
    % List1 contains zero-nine without A
    delete(List1,B,List2),
    % List2 contains zero-nine without A and B
    delete(List2,C,List3),
    % List3 contains zero-nine without A, B and C
    member(X,List3).
```

**Nothing correct:**

```
nothing_correct([A,B,C],[X,Y,Z]):-
    delete([zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine],A,ListA),
    delete(ListA,B,ListB),
    delete(ListB,C,ListC),
    member(X,ListC),
    member(Y,ListC),
    member(Z,ListC).
```

**Solution:**

```
solution(Result):-
    one_correct_well([six,eight,two],Result),
    one_correct_wrong([six,one,four],Result),
    one_correct_wrong([seven,eight,zero],Result),
    two_correct_wrong([two,zero,six],Result),
    nothing_correct([seven,three,eight],Result).
```

---

Please note that this is a fast try and therefore there are a lot of duplicate pieces of code, so it obviously can be improved

---

Second note : consider the reuse of `A` in `one_correct_well([A,B,C],[A,X,Y])` instead of using `first(A, [X,Y,Z])`

---

The predicate `delete/3` allows me to use a list from `zero` to `nine` excluding some values such as the following :

```
delete([one,two,three],two,S).
-> S = [one,three].
```

I'm not an expert in prolog, so there might be a better way of achieving this, but that's what I found with a quick search.

---

Last but not least : [here](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Break%20the%203-digits%20code.pl) is a SWISH link to a working example

Comment: Very nice +1, but could you add some comments explaining what you are doing and why please?

Comment: @G_V I've added some explanations, but if it's not enough I'll add more later

Comment: That'd be very nice, since the goal of the original question is understanding rather than a direct solution.

Comment: thank you very much, it works but I do not understand the principle, especially the role of predicat delete.

Comment: @BlackstarMC97 added a quick explanation on `delete/3` + some comments in `not_in/2` concerning `delete`. Do you understand that there are as many predicates as there are patterns for each type of predicates or should I explain this more ?

Comment: @BlackstarMC97 you're welcome ! Note that in my first predicate, I started with the same idea as yours, but we could restrict more as if `[1,2,3]` is **one-good** and `1` is the good, then there can be neither `2` nor `3` in the code, which means you can `delete` **both** `2` and `3` from the list and say X **and** Y are members of this list

Comment: @BlackstarMC97 also, have a look at my edit on the `one_correct_wrong` section and tell me what you think of it